# how to regenerate missing source paths in in a Gradle project?

Tags: gradle

how to regenerate missing source paths in in a Gradle project? I need to generate all those missing folders like `src/java`, `src/clojure` and so on. depends on project plugins. So if I add say Java plugin then `src/java/` will be generated.
I just saw that some IDE has an option to create al source paths of the plugins when it imports the project - so I assume it is possible to do from the command line.

Comment: Are you asking how to create directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in `build.gradle` by changing the sourceSets.

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java { srcDirs 'src/java' }
    clojure { srcDirs 'src/clojure' }
  }
}
```

If you also need to do the same for the `test` folders, this should work too:

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    java { srcDirs 'test/java' }
    clojure { srcDirs 'test/clojure' }
  }
}
```

---

Java plugin will not create folders for you, it instead [assumes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout) a project layout, and you are free to change this structure by doing something similar to what I have above. I have not used the `clojure` plugin, but I assume it behaves in a similar way.

If you want to list all the folders that the java plugin is making use of, you can do this:

```
println sourceSets.main.allJava.asPath
```

Displays all the files being watched by the `java` plugin.

Comment: @StebokasZiuri I'm not sure what you mean by finding out which ones are in use - in use by you or by the plugin? Maybe you want to know which folders the java plugin for example is going to search, for java files. In that case, see my edit above. The point of the matter is that the java plugin will not create folders for you - it [assumes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout) a folder structure. If you want something different, you need to specify it under the `java` portion of sourceSets